# Why is WlanOpenHandle() failing here?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wifi

I'm trying to write some WinAPI code in C which uses the Native WiFi API. At the moment, I'm stuck at the very beginning, getting a WiFi handle open.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wlanapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wlanapi.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    HANDLE *wh = NULL;
    unsigned long nv;
    int rc;

    if ((rc = WlanOpenHandle(1, NULL, &nv, wh)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("WlanOpenHandle(): ");
        switch (rc) {
            case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                printf("Invalid param.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown error.\n");
        }
        goto cleanup;
    }

    cleanup:
    WlanCloseHandle(wh, NULL);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints out "WlanOpenHandle(): Invalid param.".

Why would it be doing this? From the API documentation, it looks like I am passing everything correctly. I've also tried `2` as the first param to `WlanOpenHandle()`.

(Note that this is not my complete code, but this snippet has been tested to exhibit the mentioned issue. In the real code, there are more cases in the switch, and there is more code underneath that `goto`s to `cleanup`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a NULL pointer for the `phClientHandle` parameter. Try this:

```
HANDLE wh; // note: HANDLE, not HANDLE*
// ...
if ((rc = WlanOpenHandle(1, NULL, &nv, &wh)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) // note: &wh
```

Comment: Straight from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER - pdwNegotiatedVersion is NULL, phClientHandle is NULL, or pReserved is not NULL.`

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I overlooked what I was doing there.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I feel silly now, I was on that exact page and I simply failed to read that part of the documentation.